# Separate variables in cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have two nested C# for loops in cshtml and I want to concatenate the variables `i` and `j` with an underscore in a button tag. I've tried the following:

```
<button id="@i_@j">Click me!</button>
```

This, however, causes the engine to look for a variable called `i_`. How can I separate the variable and the string without using a space? (I don't want a space in the id).

Comment: See the answer by sleeyuen, But the fact you want to give your buttons an `id` attribute suggests something wrong with your design

Comment: I tend to agree with Stephen - perhaps consider a different approach, like using `data-` attributes: `<button data-element1="@i" data-element2="@j">Click me!</button>` Just a thought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<button id="@(i)_@(j)">Click me!</button>
```

Gives scope to your razor.

Comment: Thank you very much